# How can I make sure a callback function always has a certain amount of parameters even if they're not used?

Tags: typescript, express, parameters, unused-variables

Our backend is built with Express (1.4.0) and Typescript. A route has two callbacks:

- Success
- Error

At one point, the error callback started being ignored. After lots of debugging, we found out that [Express uses the callback parameter count](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/e1b45ebd050b6f06aa38cda5aaf0c21708b0c71e/lib/router/layer.js#L65) to identify and execute an error callback, and if it's not found, then it calls the next callback in the stack.

We realized this bug was introduced when we cleaned up the unused parameters in our code. In this case, it was `next`.

We added the fourth parameter and we added a warning comment. But **how can we prevent this from happening again?** Is there a way to add a lint rule or perhaps something with Typescript?

Comment: In my case, as `eslint` 's `no-unused-vars` would complain about a unused `next`, I had to anyways add an `eslint-disable-next-line` comment, to which I add an explanatory comment. Hopefully, that will prevent anyone from deleting the parameter during a clean up exercise, but obviously requires you to be aware of the problem when developing in the first place.